# Pass container IP across containers for config file

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker, and am attempting to create two containers, one for MySQL and one for my Node.js app, based on images from Docker's HUB.

I'd like to connect my node app to the MySQL host.

For this, I'm planning to store informations about this host [through environment variables](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables) in my config.yaml (used by [node-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)) for later use.

**My question is : how could I pass the IP address of the MySQL container to my node.js app?**

It is dynamically attributed, I vaguely know I can retrieve it with a command as `docker inspect $(docker ps -q) | grep '"IPAddress"'`, it may be a clue?

---

#### Docker-compose.yml :

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6
  environment:   
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
    - MYSQL_USER=user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
  volumes:
    - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

nodeapp:
  build: .
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=^^^^^ // will mirror the value up there, and so on
    - ...
  ports:
    - "80:3000"
  links:
    - mysql
```

#### Config.yaml :

```
app:

  port: 3000

  db:
    host: "MYSQL_HOST" // How can this be dynamic ?
    port:"MYSQL_PORT"
    database: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
    user: "MYSQL_USER"
    password: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
```

#### Dockerfile :

```
FROM    node:0.10

ADD package.json /usr/src/package.json
# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /usr/src && npm install

ADD . /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

EXPOSE  3000

CMD npm start
```

Comment: See: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run containers with docker-compose, it adds in every container in `/etc/hosts` a dynamic line with the format

```
<dynamic ip> container_name
```

Thus, when you run `docker-compose up` every container knows any other container by its name.

So, in your confing.yaml you have to change this line

```
 host: "MYSQL_HOST" // How can this be dynamic ?
```

with

```
host: mysql
```

since in `/etc/hosts` you have the dynamic association between the hostname `mysql` and the dynamic ip assigned by docker the the MySQL container.

Comment: Only containers that are linked will appear in another containers /etc/hosts file. This is a feature of docker linking, not docker compose

Comment: That's cool, thank you! Bonus question : how can I get the docker-machine IP?

Comment: What do you mean with docker-machine? The host?

Comment: @nessuno Question withdrawn. Thanks for your time!